# Official MySQL Docker container not caching queries?

Tags: mysql, docker

I tested the official MySQL Docker container (mysql:latest https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) with an about 500-700MB database.

While in my natively installed MySQL this database with one specific query takes about 1.5 seconds the first time, the following times take max. 100ms for the same query.
In my docker container this "query caching" doesn't seem to apply. The same query always takes the same amount of time.

How do I enable query caching or how to I look up these MySQL settings to apply them to my MySQL docker?

Additional information:
The query in question is an address search `WHERE` includes postal code, street name, house number, city
I already indexed these columns for the search to work faster which already halved the query execution time.

Comment: I think the thing that you need to say is the name of docker image that you are using.

Comment: @c4f4t0r added image description

Comment: if look the link that you posted "docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag

This will start a new container some-mysql where the MySQL instance uses the combined startup settings from /etc/mysql/my.cnf and /etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf, with settings from the latter taking precedence."

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this.

1) With your own config file mounting it into the container

```
-v /my/custom_config_dir:/etc/mysql/conf.d
```

That will put all your custom configs in a dir into the container.

2) Passing in the option for query cache which I'm not sure which ones you want to enable

So add the options after the mysql command

```
mysql:tag --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_uni
```